# Possible to copy Azure DevOps Boards Shared Queries to another project?

Tags: azure, powershell, devops, rest, az

I've been working on migrating all of the work items from one Azure DevOps (Services) project to another project in the same Organization.

I used the nkdAgility azure-devops-migration-tools to successfully copy the majority of existing work items across, but it did not grab our Shared Queries.

I played around with the Azure Rest API in powershell to list the queries.  I also looked at the AZ CLI suite to see if there was a way to list the queries.  I was able to find a couple at the root level, but it was not the entire list of Shared Queries.

Is this possible to accomplish through either of the above methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Google-fu was strong today! Here's a link to a script that does almost exactly what I want.
[Migrate Azure DevOps work items queries to a new organization](https://medium.com/@jkewley/migrate-azure-devops-work-items-queries-to-a-new-organization-687ebd7ea97)

The only difference is that I am staying within my Organization, so making mods accordingly.  Also, the Azure Rest API has probably evolved a bit since the original script was written, so I am updating the requests to handle that.

Thanks Josh Kewley!